# MVC3: Pass User Entered ID as a Parameter to a Controller Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, textbox, parameter-passing

I have a view where a user will enter an ID that will be passed to a controller method which will then populate a view containing the related patient record.

I am new to MVC and have been unable to get the ID from the textbox and pass it to the controller method.  I appreciate any help.

In my view:

```
@model Final.Models.Patient

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Patient_ID)
@Html.ActionLink("Patient", "Details", new { id=???? })
```

In my controller:

```
    public ViewResult Details(decimal id)
    {
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Single(p => p.Patient_ID == id);
        return View(patient);
    }
```

Thanks.

I was able to make it work with the following:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Details", "Patient")) {
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Patient_ID)
<input type="submit", value="Submit"/>



public ActionResult Details(Patient _patient)
        {
            decimal id = _patient.Patient_ID;

            Patient patient = db.Patients.Single(p => p.Patient_ID == id);
            return View(patient);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Is jQuery method acceptable for you? You can assign an id to the textbox, and then get the value (id entered by user) and then submit to your controller using $.ajax

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PatientID, new { id = "patient"})

 $.ajax({
           url: '/Home/Details',
           type: 'POST',
           data: { id: $('#patient').val()},
           async: false,
           success: function (result) {
               alert('success!');
           }
       });
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: I would like figuring out how to make it work with your method.  Im familiar with js files and referencing the jQuery library but I've never used ajax.  Does that involve just another library reference to use?  Im assuming the jQuery/ajax code would go in a js file and that I would need something in my controller as well...correct?

Comment: no, you don't need to have anything extra, reference to jquery will do. Also, your controller is just accepting the parameter called "id" in the data here, nothing else you need to change :)

Answer (score 0):

receive the model in ActionResult instead

```
@model Final.Models.Patient
@usign (@BeginForm("Details","Controller"){
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Patient_ID)
@Html.ActionLink("Patient", "Details", new { id=???? })
<input type="submit", value="Submit"/>
}
```

in your controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(Patient _patient)
    {
        decimal id = _patient.Patient_ID
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Single(p => p.Patient_ID == id);
        return View(patient);
    }
```

Comment: In order to receive the model in an ActionResult your code block for the controller would say ActionResult rather than ViewResult correct?

Comment: and Im unsure what to put in place of the question marks following id=. Also a little confused why you show patient being passed into the controller rather than id.